# How do I install packages permanently on my Beagleboard?

Tags: embedded, angstrom

I have spent some time getting my BeagleBoard XM computer up and running with the default Angstrom demo image after it has sat unopened for close to a year. I've been able to interact with it through the serial port, and then through putty. I can install packages such as Apache, and it seems to work fine.

However, with the exception of writing test files to one specific mount point, all other mount points seem to be temporary. So when I install a new package and then reboot the computer, the package is no longer there.

Is there a trick to `opkg`, or do I have to create a new image that builds the bulk of the file systems on the SD card? I am fine with adding packages and programming, but building images is tedious and daunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the demo version is mounted to a ram disk.

So YES - you must build the image.  The way I went about it was to build a Linux system on an older laptop (which of course opens its own can of worms) and build the image from there.

Once you have a working version of Angstrom that is NOT loading onto ramDisks the installation of packages is permanent and pleasantly straight-forward.